# wordpress comments only if user is logged in - integration with a site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website where users can create accounts and login to them. I've setup a Wordpress blog and I want registered users(on my site) to be able to make comments using their registered username and only if they're logged in to the site. They don't need to login separately in wordpress. Also I want this to be the only way you can put a comment to a post.

Thanks

Comment: This might be better adressed at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, check out this plugin. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/customize-your-community/ This will get rid of the wordpress looking login, and make it nice and matching your site.

Answer (score 0):

Default wordpress functionality allow user to post a comment only if they are logged in or the user can enter a comment by entering his email and name in the box provided. If you want to make the users in your site to comment on wordpress blog wothout logging in to wordpress then you need to alter some backend functionality of wordpress and combine the user table of your site and wordpress and check for user login.